# where-object in powershell

Tags: powershell

How can I club these two ?

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*|`
Where-Object {$_.displayname -like "*Database Engine Services*" } |  Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate |Format-Table -AutoSize

Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |  Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate |
Where-Object {($_.displayname -like "*Engagement*")  } |`
 Format-Table –AutoSize
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went with a RegEx approach to condensing your Where-Object filtering to a single instance, but you could also use -OR to also bring it into a single instance. Also, there is no need to do a Select-Object into a Format-Table as just using Format-Table will let you specify what properties to display.

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Where-Object {
    $_.DisplayName -match '^Database Engine Services|Engagement'
} | Format-Table DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate -AutoSize
```

Here is the alternative using -OR with your -LIKE statement:

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Where-Object {
    $_.DisplayName -LIKE 'Database Engine Services*' -OR $_.DisplayName -LIKE '*Engagement*'
} | Format-Table DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate -AutoSize
```

Comment: Thank you Sir @boeprox. I am big fan of you and your Get-SQLInstance and I used to automate my project stuff. Yes this fixed my issue. Thank you sir.